# Providing a function alias in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll

I'm looking for a way to define an unmangled alias for an exported function in a DLL compiled with GCC.

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805560/2245528), Visual Studio supports

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:SomeFunction=_SomeFunction@@@23mangledstuff#@@@@")
```

to specify that an exported function shall have a given alias. I'm looking for something similar in GCC. [The GCC function attribute docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) suggest `__attribute__ ((alias ("target")))` will do the trick, but this just generates a mangled function name:

```
#undef DLL_EXPORT
#ifdef CCDLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_EXPORT __stdcall __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT __stdcall __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_EXPORT CCDLL_v1* GetCCDLL_premangled();

DLL_EXPORT CCDLL_v1* GetCCDLL () __attribute__ ((alias ("_Z19GetCCDLL_premangledv")));
```

and here's the .def file from the resulting DLL:

```
EXPORTS
    _Z19GetCCDLL_premangledv @1
    _Z8GetCCDLLv @2
```

The original function is exported and mangled as expected, but so is the function alias. If I drop the `DLL_EXPORT` from the function alias, I expect it would remain unmangled, but it's also not exported from the DLL. I thought the stdcall calling convention might be mangling the function alias, but when I removed it from the `DLL_EXPORT` definition, the .def file remained exactly the same.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7650245/2245528) suggests I can define an alias using `--defsym=alias_name=target`, but ld doesn't seem to recognize this and I can't find anything in the [official GCC linker docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) at all.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for, or does GCC just not support unmangled aliases for exported functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try in your .def file:

```
normalName=mangled_name @ 1
```

Another way may be to define an extern "C" function that calls the internal C++ one, and export that.

Comment: Be careful, anything that (directly or indirectly) uses C++ features **will not work** when called from plain C.

Comment: The .def file worked out perfectly. I'd been setting it up wrong; thanks for showing the proper way to do it.

Comment: @vonbrand Can you develop on that?  I have been using for some years `extern "C"` wrappers around C++ functions to use opencv which is C++ from my C code.  The only thing I needed was to use `void *` in the interface to pass pointers to C++ `class`es around C functions.  Everything works fine even with `-O3 -flto`, so from my experience, **it will work**.

Comment: @vonbrand on multiple platforms including MS Windows libc functions are themselves implemented in C++ so I'd cast a doubt on this