# How to define a function in C++ that is simply an explicit template expansion?

Tags: c++, templates, delegates

Say I am creating a C++ library that defines a `futz` function (among other things)
with the signature as specified in a `schmooze.h` header:

```
#ifndef SCHMOOZE_H
#define SCHMOOZE_H
 
// ... 
double futz(int a, double b);

#endif
```

In the implementation of this library there is a template function
named `festoon` that I want
to explicitly instantiate and define as the `futz` function:

```
// .... 
#include "schmooze.h"

namespace {
   template <typename T>
   T festoon(int a, T b) {
      // ...
   }
}

// ???? define futz as an instance of festoon ????
double futz(int a, double b) = festoon<double>;
```

I don't want to put the `festoon` template definition in the header (I should not have to).
I merely want to create a function `futz` that is an instance of the `festoon` template that I can compile separately and link against.
There is a way to [explicitly instantiate template functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function), but is unable to
instantiate a function that I can link against (and have different name).
Essentially I want the compiler to generate code for a specific function that
is an expansion of a local template.

I could do this

```
double futz(int a, double b) {
   return festoon<double>(a,b);
}
```

but that generates an extra function call and seems awkward.

**EDIT:**

As user @n.m.couldbeanAI pointed out, it is indeed possible to explicitly generate an instance of a function template.
For example:

```
template <typename T>
T festoon(int a, T b) {
   return b/T(a);
}

template double festoon<double>(int a, double b);
```

I can compile and find that there is indeed an instance of this
function in the resulting objecting file:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++11 festoon.cpp
$ nm festoon.o
0000000000000000 T __Z7festoonIdET_iS0_
$ c++filt __Z7festoonIdET_iS0_
double festoon<double>(int, double)
```

I guess I originally did not expect the angle bracket notation
`<double>` would be retained in the function name and that
is why I could not link against it.

Comment: There's nothing in the standard C++ for this. You can probably trick the linker, in an implementation-specific manner, into treating the name `futz` as an alias for whatever mangled name `festoon<double>` ends up having. Though on second thought, in your example `festoon<double>` has internal linkage and so wouldn't be exported as a linkable name.

Comment: What is your proof that it "generates an extra function call"? I would expect that current C++ compilers optimize it away with a single jump instructions, and with LTO there may not even be a JMP instruction at all, but just symbol table hackery, pointing `futz` and the mangled template symbol at the same function.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah I am sort of surprised that C++ does not have a mechanism for this. The ancient hack of using the pre-processor to define a separably linkable function from a macro work fine. Seems trivial for the compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are probably right in that an extra function call is not generated. It just seems like there should be a more direct way to do this.

Comment: Can `futz` be a function pointer instead?

Comment: @Eljay I would prefer to avoid avoid that.

Comment: All instantiations of the festoon template are called festoon. If you want futz to do the same thing as one of those, just make it call one of those.

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582666/providing-a-function-alias-in-gcc

Comment: @Klaus no I hadn't -- I didn't consider I would have to go down any esoteric paths to do this. I find it strange that C++ has no simple mechanism for saying "generate an instance of this template with these parameters" -- even w/o the name change this doesn't seem possible.

Comment: *C++ has no simple mechanism for saying "generate an instance of this template with these parameters"* --- false. Search for "explicit template instantiations".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Actually that was the very first thing I searched for. I tried it out and the clang++ compiler would *not* generate and instance and place in the compiled object file. Try it. It simply does not generate and compile the instance.

Comment: You are mistaken. Show what you have tried and I will show you your error.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You are correct. I added an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but that generates an extra function call and seems awkward.

That's the best way of doing it. The compiler will optimize out the extra function call, so you don't have to worry about that at all.

But if you insist, here's how to do it in GCC:

```
// main.cpp

void foo(double d);

int main()
{
    foo(3.14);
}
```

```
// foo.cpp

template <class T>
void print(T t) {
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

template void print<double>(double);

void foo(double) 
    __attribute__((weak, alias("_Z5printIdEvT_"))); // mangled name
```

Obviously, this is not great because you have to hard-code the mangled identifier and maintain it if the function signature changes.

Comment: The extra function call is the way to go. It might be fun to try the name mangling you suggest just to see if anyone reviews my code and says says WTH?

Comment: @wcochran That's a good way to test how diligent your reviewers are

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot be defined as delegates of other functions.
You're right that wrapping `festoon` in a `futz` function would generate an extra function call, but only on debug builds (no optimizations).
With optimizations enabled, that extra call should be eliminated.

A more direct way of delegating functions would be function pointers and function references.
In your case, a function reference would be better because it would act as more of an "alias" for another function. A function pointer could still be copied and passed around like any other object.

```cpp
namespace {
   template <typename T>
   T festoon(int a, T b) {
      return a + b;
   }
}

constexpr double (&futz)(int a, double b) = festoon<double>;
// or
constexpr auto& futz = festoon<double>;
```

On debug builds, this would require loading the function address which `futz` stores from memory, and then making an indirect call. However, any optimizing compiler is going to turn this into a direct call on a release build.

---

*Note 1: Since `festoon` has internal linkage, it would be more appropriate if `futz` was also in an unnamed namespace.*

*Note 2: it's theoretically possible that `futz` doesn't get turned into a `festoon` call (even with optimizations) if the compiler runs out of optimization passes before it simplifies that call. However, that scenario is very unlikely.*

*Note 3: `constexpr` is optional. It doesn't enable additional optimizations, but it does make `futz` usable in a constant expression.*

*See also: [What is a C++ delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9568150/5740428)*

Comment: If this is going to a cpp file (as OP intends, I think) the function reference cannot be `constexpr`. That's not great because the order of initialization of global variables in different translation units is unspecified.

Comment: @AykhanHagverdili that the order is unspecified only matters for dynamic initialization. `futz` is initialized by a constant, so there is no dynamic initialization, only static initialization. The order of initialization is also only unspecified for multiple translation units, and since `festoon` has internal linkage, I suspect the whole example is TU-local.