# Mocking library functions in C

Tags: c, testing, linker, mocking

I want to mock functions of the c lib such as `malloc` without altering too much the original source file (the one that uses malloc).

I tried including a header file "mock.h" like

```
#ifndef MOCK_H_
# define MOCK_H_
# ifdef MOCK_MODE

#  include <sys/types.h>

extern void *my_mock_malloc(size_t n);
void    *malloc(size_t n) __attribute__((weak, alias ("my_mock_malloc")));

# endif /* MOCK_MODE */
#endif /* !MOCK_H_ */
```

but it gives me an error

```
in file included from ...:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:466:14: error: ‘malloc’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘my_mock_malloc’
 extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
```

[GCC alias to function outside of translation unit -AKA- is this even the right tool for the job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649979/gcc-alias-to-function-outside-of-translation-unit-aka-is-this-even-the-right-t) gives a partial solution: using the linker I create an alias on a symbol. I can now compile with `-Xlinker --defsym "malloc"="my_mock_malloc"`. The problem is that all my `.o` files are linked using this option and thus the unit testing framework I use ([check](http://check.sourceforge.net/)) is affected by the mocking (and thus it receives is SIGSEGV when I make my mock function return `NULL`).

Is there a way to perform such symbol aliasing locally, so I can make my tesing framework use the real malloc? Os is there a better solution than this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which is to include a header file `mock.h` like

```
#ifndef MOCK_H_
# define MOCK_H_
# ifdef MOCK_MODE

#  include <sys/types.h>

extern void *my_mock_malloc(size_t n);
#  define malloc(x) (my_mock_malloc(x))

# endif /* MOCK_MODE */
#endif /* !MOCK_H_ */
```

but I am still curious about another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Most implementations of the C language specify all symbols of the libc as *weak,* that is, you can override them as needed. Try it out! You can write your own function named `malloc` and it automatically replaces the library supplied `malloc`. Have a look at your platforms documentation as there are a couple more functions (like `free`, `realloc`, `calloc`, etc) that you need to implement for a `malloc` replacement to be complete.

Comment: I tried removing the `#define` from my answer here, and renaming the function to `malloc`. It compiled cleanly but hung.

Comment: Did you implement all other needed functions, too? What platform are you working on?

Comment: You'll see in my answer what I did. `my_malloc` prints a message saying it was called, and returns `NULL`. There are no other needed functions in that example. When I removed the `#include <stdlib.h>` and the `#define` and renamed the function to `malloc` it compiled but did not run - hung. MSVC 2009.

Comment: That's because GNU printf calls malloc internally! You get an infimite loop. And again, you must override the other functions, too or weirf behaviour occurs.

Comment: Ahhhhh I only really tested `#define` for local use. But I wonder then why `printf` worked in my original answer (and Gme is Gnot Gnu) -;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define malloc my_malloc

void *my_malloc(size_t size) {
    printf ("Called my_malloc\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char * array = malloc(100);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Called my_malloc
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not a full answer to your question, you will find that CppUTest is very useful for testing C code as well, and includes most of the malloc/free library in its mock capabilities, allowing you to control malloc failure and so on. It's also very good for debugging memory allocation issues since it uses a debug allocator.

I found that the framework documentation was however a little lacking in detail and examples.

When I used that framework "in anger" a couple of years ago, I found it necessary to implement my own mocked strdup() function, which I did within the CppUTest source.

https://cpputest.github.io/mocking_manual.html

I added the DeathHandler facility as well, to help capture and diagnose segfaults during test.