# How I can make alias on external defined function in C?

Tags: c, gcc, alias, weak

During compiling this C code

```
extern void Default_Handler(void);
void NMI_Handler(void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("Default_Handler")));
```

I've recive this

```
error: 'NMI_Handler' aliased to undefined symbol 'Default_Handler'
```

How I can make alias on external defined function?

Compiler:

```
gcc version 7.2.1 20170904 (release) [ARM/embedded-7-branch revision 255204] (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major)
```

Comment: All functions are implicitly extern. You don't need extern prefix for functions.

Comment: function `void Default_Handler(void)` exist in other .c file

Comment: Is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649979/gcc-alias-to-function-outside-of-translation-unit-aka-is-this-even-the-right-t) helpful?

Comment: It don't work with weak attribute.

Answer (score 7):

To alias an external function, you can use `objcopy`. Here's an example:

Say I have the definition of a function and I alias it, like in the following program (called `myimp.c`):

```
// myimp.c
int
myadd(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}

int
coolguy (int x, int y) __attribute__((alias("myadd")));
```

If we compile this (but don't link) we get an object file and we can check out its symbols:

```
# compile
$ cc -c myimp.c
# look at the symbols
$ nm myimp.o
0000000000000000 T coolguy
0000000000000000 T myadd
```

So we can see that the `__attribute__((alias("myadd"))` is simply adding a symbol `coolguy` with the same value, 0000000000000000, as `myadd`. If you look in the `man` page for nm, it will say that `T` means it is a global symbol in the `.text` section. This makes sense because the function is not `static` and comprises instructions (as opposed to data).

So if we have the object file, but not the source, and we want to add a function alias we can do so using `objcopy --add-symbol`.

Say we have the object file resulting from compiling this source code:

```
// myimp2.c
int
myadd(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

Compiling as above, we'll get `myimp2.o`, whose symbol table tools like this:

```
# look at the symbols
$ nm myimp2.o
0000000000000000 T myadd
```

So we want to add the `coolguy` symbol, which we do as follows

```
# objcopy --add-symbol coolguy=.text:0000000000000000,global myimp2.o myimp2_augmented.o
```

Look at the documentation on `--add-symbol` in the `objcopy` `man` page. Basically `.text` specifies the section, after the colon the value, and then `global` I found by passing a bad type and `objcopy` failed and told me a list of the valid types, from which I chose `global`.

Try running `nm` on `myimp2_augmented.o`, you'll see that we've added the symbol.

Now you should be able to link with `myimp2_augmented.o` instead of `myimp.o` and your program can call `coolguy` without linking errors.

Comment: Here is what I don't get about this example: in C code, it is explicit that `coolguy` is an alias of `myadd`; so presumably if you `printf` them both as pointers (`%p`), you should get the same address. However, I don't see how `objcopy --add-symbol coolguy=.text:0000000000000000,global` establishes an alies to specifically `myadd` - it looks like it just enters a symbol in the table, without it pointing to anything?

Comment: try adding this to the above source code and then compile as before:
`int
anotherfun(int x)
{
    return x - 1;
}

int
blahblah (int x) __attribute__((alias("anotherfun")));
`
You will see this symbol table
`
% nm myimp.o
0000000000000018 T anotherfun
0000000000000018 T blahblah
0000000000000000 T coolguy
0000000000000000 T myadd
`
So I imagine one would change 0000000000000000 to 0000000000000018 in the above `objcopy` command to alias one of those new symbols.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445227/193887), add the following to your linker command file:

```
PROVIDE(NMI_Handler = Default_Handler);
```

(And remove the weak alias declaration from the C code.)

Answer (score 1):

here NMI_Handler has a weak definition attribute means that if NMI_Handler is not defined then definition of Default_Handler will be used for NMI_Handler. generally there are strong definition available for interrupts like NMI_Handler or Default_Handler.you might need to add those file in your compilation to remove error.if you wants to handle NMI_Handler in your own way then you can define it somewhere and that definition will be included instead of weak one.

Comment: you need to define NMI_Handler or Default_Handler if your code is not including it in compilation.

Comment: I know, that external function need defination. I have it. I want to make alias on that external defined function.

Comment: if you have already defined Default_Handler somewhere and it gets included in compilation then it should't throw error.

Comment: The problem is that (per GCC manual) given `void f () __attribute__ ((weak, alias ("fred")));`, "It is an error if ‘fred’ is not defined in the same translation unit." That case in question here is one where fred is defined in _another_ translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

It's popular to employee weak and alias attribute to implement override mechanism for native C project especially in cases of firmware projects.

Both of declaration and definition can be noted by `__attribute__((weak))` and its linking priority rules is related to if any declaration exists in a head file.

It would be good tactic that just to code and compile it. Then see what would happen when linking is look for its definition. I usually check symbols by `-Wl,-trace,-trace-symbol=ANY_FUNCTION_NAME_YOU_WANT` and `nm OBJECT_FILE_NAME`.

Usually I just create a weak attribute function definition and let other objects override it.
An example shown as below:

`In C file:`

```
//non-exported weak attribute definition
__attribute__((weak)) void startup_handler_dummy(void) {
        printf("[%s][%s]Entry (NO OVERRIDE HANLDER COMES HERE)\n", __FILE__, __func__);
}

//weak and alias attribute declaration
void startup_handler_dummy_impl(void) __attribute__((weak, alias("startup_handler_dummy")));

//exported weak attribute definition
__attribute__((weak)) void startup_handler(void) {
    startup_handler_dummy_impl();
}
```

`In header file:`

```
#ifndef _BOARD_H_
#define _BOARD_H_
#define STARTUP_HANDLER startup_handler //to export symbol
#endif
```

Hope my code can help :)

And you can see more details and program screen-shots on [MyGitHub](https://github.com/MouChiaHung/ATTRIBUTE_WEAK).