# How can I make an alias to a standard library function?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to make an alias to the standard library function `fmaf` with the alias attribute.

```
#include <math.h>
float float_fma(float x, float y, float z) __attribute__((alias("fmaf")));
int main() {
   float_fma(0,0,0);
   return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error "undefined symbol 'fmaf'".

```
<source>:2:11: error: 'float_fma' aliased to undefined symbol 'fmaf'
    2 |     float float_fma(float x, float y, float z) __attribute__((alias("fmaf")));
      |       
^~~~~~~~~
```

How can I make an alias to `fmaf` ?

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings when using `fmaf()` directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can make alias on external defined function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660176/how-i-can-make-alias-on-external-defined-function-in-c)

Comment: What do you try to accomplish?